# Trying to establish connection to External Database

Tags: php, functions, database, wpdb

I'm trying to get a connection to a separate external database from the database the wordpress site depends on. I have a PHP file inside the same location of my theme, it is basically a blank PHP it has the needed PHP tags.

I'm trying to make a connection using what I found online this is what the **whole** file looks like:

```
<?php
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','db_name','xxx.xxx.xxx');
?>
```

When I try to make a connection with the correct credentials I get an error in my WPEngine Live Site Log that says:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'wpdb' not found in /nas/content/live/...`

How do I go about fixing this issue, so that I can connect to my external database?

Comment: That looks like it should work. How are you calling this code? Is it in a theme, a plugin, ...? If possible, please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/228046/edit) to provide some more context.

Comment: @PatJ I extended/provided more details

Comment: @PatJ Do I have to make an include tag so it runs wp-db.php?

Comment: Instead of putting your php in a separate file add it to your wp-config file and you should be all set. You may need to make $mydb a global but, I think that's it; looking for an old set up I did for more details . . .

Comment: @dg4220 I think I found a solution! One sec, I'll get back to you!

Comment: @PatJ Just posted a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved, not sure if the connection to the database will work, but the error with wpdb connection was fixed. It was quite easy fix once I found out what the file dependence was. This is what you need to do:

In the file you are trying to use wpdb you need to add code before you can use the class:

```
<?php require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
```

Note* You may need to change how far back in the directory you go depending on your install or depending on the location of your php template/file.

It should run wpdb without any errors.

Comment: You saved me a total hour of work. Thanks man 